# python: can't open file in macbook terminal - [Errno 2]!

Tags: python, macos, file, terminal, errno

In my macbook air terminal I wrote

```
python eggshell.py
```

but I got this error

> python: can't open file 'eggshell.py': [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory s-user:/ user$

After I got that error I tried a number of things, like specifying exactly were eggshell.py is:

```
python Users/myuser/Eggshell/eggshell.py
```

Doing that just gave me a different Errno 2 error:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'modules/commands/macOS'

If you have anything that can help me figure this out, I'd be incredibly grateful, thanks. P.S I'll attach an image of where the eggshell.py is located

eggshell.py is actually located in a folder in my documents, but it shows up in the documents too, so I really don't know why `python eggshell.py` doesn't work.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you in the directory where `eggshell.py` is? (what do `pwd` and `ls` output?)

Comment: I'm such a noob, such a simple thing I missed! Thanks Izaak!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be in the directory the eggshell.py was located. (use `cd` to navigate)